# How to turn on the horizontal scroll bar in text editor

Tags: text-editor

Is seems strange that the text editor has a vertical scroll bar but not a horizontal one.

Bender uses Shift-MMB to 'pan' most views, but I couldn't get it working on the text editor.  I don't like 'word wrap' for long lines. Is it possible to enable the horizontal bar?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the <kbd>MMB</kbd> (without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key) to grab and slide the view in the text editor.

Comment: Thanks, I am so used to panning views with shift-MMB in Blender that I forgot to try the simpler alternative.

Comment: @ShungChing - actually MMB is the common way to scroll a view around - only the 3dview needs shift for panning, but the text editor and properties are the only ones that holding shift breaks. You can also enable line wrapping instead of scrolling sideways.

Comment: @sambler, you are right! I pan 3dviews and toolbar strips frequently. My left hand finger subconsciously hold down shift when necessary, yet my mind tell me that I used the shift all the time!

Comment: @ShungChing Go ahead and click the *Accept* button (the check mark under the vote buttons) if this answer solved your issue. It will help out the site stats, and my reputation. Thanks!